# Drupal 7 I need to change the sku directly in the commerce_product table and want to know if this is possible to do without creating a drush script

Tags: drupal-7, product, commerce

I need to change the sku directly in the commerce_product table and want to know if this is possible to do without creating a drush script.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by changing the same sku in both commerce_product & commerce_product_revision then truncating all of the cache tables.

```
UPDATE `commerce_product` SET `sku` = 456 WHERE `sku` = 123;

UPDATE `commerce_product_revision` SET `sku` = 456 WHERE `sku` = 123;
```